# How to prevent download files from FTP?

Tags: ftp, proftpd

Can i prevent download all files for account by ftp? Because i will pay money for freelancer and at my site i has very important files, I need to allow changing files by ftp, but to prevent any downloading of files by ftp, can I do this? I use ProFTPD on my Ubuntu vds server.

Comment: No. If you can read them you can download them.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109087/how-do-large-companies-protect-their-source-code

Answer (score 0):

You might try using something like this in your `proftpd.conf`:

```
<Directory />
  <Limit READ>
    DenyUser user1
    DenyUser user2
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

This says to deny/reject any "read" commands (such as `RETR` (RETRieve, used for downloads) for the named users (in this example, `user1`, `user2`), but to allow those read commands for every other user.

Hope this helps!